# Ошибка при работе с Vk Api для ботов

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, url, urllib

Столкнулся с ошибкой

> raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
>   requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '{'upload_url': 'https://pu.vk.com/c830408/upload.php?act=do_add&mid=350066825&aid=-3&gid=0&hash=29074490462289ddb5f2440fff1780bf&rhash=be1ba2a531c5689f6db20822c322f124&swfupload=1&api=1&mailphoto=1', 'album_id': -3, 'user_id': 350066825}'

Вот мой код:

```
pfile = post(vk.photos.getMessagesUploadServer(peer_id = 476525772, files = {'photo': webpage }))
    pfile = json.dumps(pfile)
    pfile = json.loads(pfile)
    photos = vk.photos.saveMessagesPhoto(server = pfile['server'], photo = pfile['photo'], hash = pfile['hash'])[0]
    sendPhoto = 'photo' + str(photo['owner_id']) + '_' + str(photo['id'])
```

Вот код переменной `webpage`:

```
url = 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrari_FF#/media/File:Ferrari_FF_Autosalon_Genf_1.JPG'
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()
```

Comment: Такое ощущение, что.. по ошибке в `post` попал не url, а `json`. Из этого предположения выходит, что правильно будет так: `rs = vk.photos.getMessagesUploadServer(peer_id = 476525772, files = {'photo': webpage })` `url = rs['upload_url']` `pfile = post(url)`

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял Вы используете модуль    [vk_api](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/).

Тогда можно использовать класс **VkUpload**:

```python
from vk_api import VkUpload

upload = VkUpload('''объект VkApi''')

photos = upload.photo(photos='''путь или file-like объект''')[0]
sendPhoto = f'photo{photos["owner_id"]}_{photos["id"]}'
```

Подробное описание класса можно посмотреть [тут](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upload.html)